# How to change menu items href without 2 items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm changed my menu items href by jQuery with check website adress:

```
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("en") > -1) {
    var link = $('#main-nav a');
        link.each(function(){
    this.href += '-en';
});
    };
```

And it's working really good but I don't want to add string '-en' for 2 special links. How I can do that ?

I tried to do something like this, but it's not working:

```
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("en") > -1) {
    var link = $('#main-nav a');
        link.each(function(){
            if(link.href === "#special1") || (link.href === "#special2"){
                return this.href;
            } else{
    this.href += '-en';
}
});
    };
```

Comment: Your `if` statement has syntax error. Change it to: `if(link.href === "#special1" || link.href === "#special2") {`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this, but still all links have modified href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement has syntax error. The first `)` closes the `if` expression. Change it to:

```
if (link.href === "#special1" || link.href === "#special2") {
```

Also note that `href` *property* returns an absolute path. You should either get the `href` *attribute* of the element using `.getAttribute()` method or read the `hash` property of the anchor.

And you should also change `link.href` to `this.href`.

I'd suggest:

```
var blackList =  ["#special1",  "#special2"];
$('#main-nav a').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(this.getAttribute('href'), blackList) === -1;
}).prop('href', function(_, href) {
   return href + '-en';
});
```

Another option is using the `.not()` method:

```
 $('#main-nav a')
      // exclude the elements
     .not('[href="#special1"], [href="#special2"]')
      // update `href` properties
     .prop('href', function(_, href) { return href + '-en'; });
```

Comment: Vohuman, thanks its working really good, but my links have only href to section id and when this function is running and add string, display full website href "http://localhost:8080/en/#section-en" but i want to only add '-en' to href like "#section-en". How I can fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, there is an error in your `if` condition. `.href` returns the absolute path, such as http://www.domain.com/yourpage.html#special1. So, you have few ways to do that, like below.

```
if(link.href.indexOf("#special1") !== -1 || link.href.indexOf("#special2") !== -1) {}

if(link.href.match(/\#special[1-2]/i) !== null) {}

if(link.attr("href") === "#special1" || link.attr("href") === "#special2") {}
```

So, your code could also be written as:

```
var $links = $('#main-nav a');
$links.filter(function() {
     return this.href.match(/\#special[1-2]/i) === null
}).prop("href", function() {
    return this.href  + "-en";
});
```